# Colour half an icon, using css

Tags: jquery, css

i've got a progress bar, which represents the stages of a message being approved. The message can be partially approved, and required a second approval. I therefore, need to represent the following, with only half of the icon in green. Is this possible?

```
<div class="stepwizard-step">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle" disabled="disabled">1</button>
  <p>partially approved/approved</p>
</div>
```

***EDIT***
[image]

***EDIT***
I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1

***EDIT***
Alex, almost there, just need to move the text forward:

[image]

css is:

```
       .partially-approved {
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .partially-approved:before {
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            right: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

and this is being applied :

```
$('button#stage3').attr("class", "btn partially-approved btn-circle");
```

Comment: So the shape is a circle only? Can you provide a fiddle of this problem?

Comment: You could use an icon where part of the icon is transparent, then set a background color, behind the icon to change that half

Comment: Nico, can't post any data/examples, due to the nature of the site, however i've added a screen shot above. Basically, stage 3 needs to have half coloured green

Comment: You need to at least provide us with the relevant CSS, otherwise how else can we work with your example?

Comment: Billy, the css is there, it's bootstrap buttons. Sorry i should of made that cleaer.

Answer (score 5):

I made a quick example for you here:

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5kKc4/)

CSS:

```
#circle{
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#progress{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

With this you can also edit it with javascript by simply setting the width of the progress to 100%

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a linear gradient

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yctnH)

```
.approved {
  background-color: #bada55;
}

.approval_awaited {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #bada55 0%, #bada55 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I would fallback to 'orange' (or other 3rd/4th color) for non-supporting browsers

Comment: That's a good fallback, but this can be achieved without any unsupported methods ;) (@Paradoxis got it)

Comment: He adds an extra element doesn't he (?) but OK

Comment: He does, but it's 100% compatible with any device

Comment: It should, in newer versions of IE...(assuming the right syntax) but I just offered it as an alternative.

Comment: It worked fine in Firefox, didnt' work at all in IE 9

Comment: Yeah, IE9 doesn't support that syntax, MSfilter probably would be needed. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3):

Using the :after CSS syntax you could do something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/jY9fu/

```
.btn {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn:before {
    background: green;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This uses the same HTML you have, just an extra little bit of CSS

Edit: Updated the padding to off-center the text a little. See here http://jsfiddle.net/jY9fu/1/

Second edit: Without adding extra element you could utilise the content property of the :after psuedo-element such as http://jsfiddle.net/jY9fu/2/ - but you'd need to add a data-attribute of the step if it's to be dynamic.

Comment: Alex, wont this always set it to half green?

Comment: Yes, but you could easily just use a specific class selector instead. My example was to demonstrate the CSS for it.

Comment: :-) need it in the middle. are there any z-index's we can apply here?

Comment: Middle example added, but it's not as pretty!

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is a bit late... But I was slow with the JSfiddle. My answer is using a different approach, since you will need to have `<span>` to get the numbers about the pseudo elments. But the answer with the background-gradient is the best imo. If you can use it, i'd do it.

Here is one idea:

```
.progress
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}

.progress > li
{
    margin: 0 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height:1em;
    background-color: gray;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progress > li:not(.half).done,
.progress > li.done:before
{
    background-color: green;
}

.progress > li:before
{
   bottom:0;
   top: 50%;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   content:"";
   position: absolute;   
}

.progress > li:last-of-type
{
    margin-right: 0
}

.progress > li > span
{
    position: relative;
}
```

Going with this HTML:

```
<ul class="progress">
    <li class="done"><span>1</span></li>
    <li class="done"><span>2</span></li>
    <li class="half done"><span>3</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>4</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/dq7pf/3/

Comment: Nice, but I'm not sure a left-to-right structure suits the progress being from bottom-to-top. Seems to go against the flow somewhat

Comment: Good point Alex, but I'am sure he will figure out how to alter that. I was thinking about a "filling bubble". But left to right should be more natural indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say split your icon into two transparent parts and change each part bg color according to the approval state .

or use two icons over each other one is transparent and displayed to user , the other is colored and it's opacity is 0 , then animate it's width to 50%  or 100% according to the approval state .